# How to patch the boot information table in ISO master?

Tags: iso

I'm using ISO master and I'm trying to create a bootable image file. I put in stage2_eltorito. Now, how do I patch the boot information table?

I remember when I used Windows I would use Imgburn and check off Patch boot information table.

Comment: FYI, you can still use IMGBurn in Ubuntu, if you want to take the time to install [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/download/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Tools>Boot Record>Add. Then you can select what kind of emulation you want (you can even select to have no emulation).